# How do you move data at one memory location to another in RISCV programming?

Tags: assembly, memory, cpu-registers, riscv

I am new to RISC-V programming and assembly programming in general.

I want to move a 32 bit word from an address in memory, say `0x04000000`, to another address say `0x00000190`.

Do I have to load the data to a GPR first (using `lw`?), then store to the new address (e.g. `sw`?)? Or is there a more direct way?

Is there anything wrong with these instructions:

```
lw x8, 0(x67108864)
sw x8, 192(x0)
```

thanks

Comment: Yes, you'll have to first move the datum into a register and then store it to memory.  As far as I know, RISC-V does not have any memory-to-memory instructions.

Comment: RISC V, like MIPS (others, ARM, PowerPC) is a [load-store architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load%E2%80%93store_architecture), so yeah, if the data is not already in the CPU, then load it and if you want a copy in memory somewhere else, store it.

Comment: @fuz: I'd be very surprised if RISC-V had any memory<->memory instructions; like MIPS, it sticks to its RISC design philosophy even when that's inconvenient (like lacking add-with-carry).   David Patterson was one of the primary architects of both.  And there's not really any good reason to have memory-to-memory copies as a single instruction, other than stuff like how x86 uses that as a way to give access to optimized microcode that uses loads/stores wider than integer registers (for a whole memcpy), useful for kernel code that can't use SIMD. Unless you go down that rabbit hole, not worth it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to encode that load instruction on RISC V, as it only allows for 12-bits of immediate/offset, and, it must follow the regular base + displacement form usually written as `disp(reg)`.  Some assemblers will accept immediates of that size by expanding that line into multiple machine code instructions.

There are two additional instructions that can help form larger immediates:

- `LUI` — Load Upper Immediate provides for 20 bits of immediate that when combined in sequence with an I-Type instruction (which offer 12 bits of immediate) allows for a 32-bit immediate in 2 instructions.
- `AUIPC` — Add upper immediate to the PC also provides for 20 bits of immediate and adds the immediate to the PC to form PC-relative addressing capability.

Additionally we can use shifts and other instructions as well.

Even if that load were encodable, the `x` is a typo, since you want x4000000, aka 67,108,864<sub>10</sub> (not x67108864).

---

That store instruction will encode is ok.

Comment: It looks like they were trying to write `67108864(x0)`, which would parse ok and could plausibly be handled as a pseudo-instruction by a forgiving assembler.  `x4000000` is also wrong, missing a leading 0.  `x4000000` is either an invalid register number, or a symbol name, since it starts with a letter.  `lw x1, 0x4000000` could work on an assembler that supported pseudo-instructions, perhaps as LUI/LW using the destination register as a temporary to generate the address.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answers. Just clear my head... I can use a `LUI` to load first 20 bits of an address to a GPR. Then use `ADDI` to fill the bottom 12 bits in the GPR. Then use the `LW` instruction to a different GPR to load the actual data to a register. The `SW` to write back to memory will work because 192 it is not using more than 12 bits

Comment: Yes.  You can do LUI t0, uuuu then ADDI t0, t0, xxx, then LW t1, 0(t0).  But also, sometimes you can skip the ADDI and put the xxx in the LW in place of the 0 offset.

Answer (score 2):

I have had/issues with the volatile pointer thing, but it works here.  You can have the tools show you how to do it...sometimes...

```
#define ONE (*((volatile unsigned int *)0x04000000))
#define TWO (*((volatile unsigned int *)0x00000100))
void fun ( void )
{
    TWO=ONE;
}
```

which, for me, gives

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   040007b7            lui x15,0x4000
   4:   439c                lw  x15,0(x15)
   6:   10f02023            sw  x15,256(x0) # 100 <fun+0x100>
   a:   8082                ret
```

you can often just use the li pseudo instruction and the assembler will pick the right combination of lui, addi, for you.

Comment: That looks like a useful way of doing it. Although theres a few things not clear. E.g. It looks to me `lui x15, 0x4000` is loading 16 bits, whereas it should be loading 20? I would of expected it to generate `lui x15, 0x40000`? Also, I would have expected issues with `lw  x15,0(x15)`. Will this not overwrite the data in x15? Shouldnt it be using some sort of `ADD` or `ADDI`? (Its zeros here anyway but potentially a problem otherwise?)

Comment: lui loads the top 20 bits with the immediate in the instruction and the lower 12 are zeros, often then would use addi or orri to fill in those lower bits.

Comment: 0x04000   is the immediate so 0x4000 = 0x04000 gives 0x04000000 as the value in the register the disassembler didnt pad to 20 bits

Comment: Yes so just didnt pad properly sounds about right. Thanks again